# SAP UI5 :: drag and drop with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am looking for drag and drop with links like below gif. I have also checked this ::

```
UI5Object.extend("DraggableDelegate", {
    constructor: function (oControl) {
        this.oControl = oControl;
    },

    onAfterRendering: function () {
        this.oControl.$().draggable({
            cancel: false
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/loqeguridu/edit?html,output but linking the elements is not possible.

Is it possible to have drag and drop with links in SAP UI5 ?

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg41q.gif)

[sampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZUU6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something useful for the same.SAP UI 5 uses D3.js which has drag and drop features.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Directed Graph Editor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    </head>

    <body></body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rco31ofe/2/

Answer (score 0):

All SAP UI5 controls support drag&drop,because they are core elements and those provide function https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element%23methods/addDragDropConfig.

You provide a function which is called on drop start and another function for drop. For lists you bind to „items“ aggregation to enable individual items for D&D.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3ddb6cde6a8d416598ac8ced3f5d82d5

You do not need to use JQuery or change elements of Dom directly. Keep in mind whenever you really need to change elements of dom, you need to subscribe to the „after rendering“ event of the control and repeat changes after each rendering, because every rendering will drop your changes. For custom controls you have all freedom to add dom changes to the „renderer“, even SAP control´s renderers like sap.m.InputRenderer provide functions you can just implement when extending i.e. sap.m.Input, so you can put you own dom elements on top of the input field or just add a clickable decorator.